# Remove the delete link from pages without a plugin

Tags: functions, pages

I have created a number of pages and don't want the person managing the site to be able to delete them. I don't want to use a plugin and there is probably some code that could go in the functions.php file to achieve this. Does anyone know how to hide or remove the 'delete' link if you are viewing all the available pages?

I found this post [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29357/how-to-disable-page-delete), but it is 6 years old so not sure if it's still good in 2018.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable page delete](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29357/how-to-disable-page-delete)

Comment: It's still accurate.

Comment: I see this has been marked as a duplicate. That is why I posted the link to ask if that 6 year old post was still okay to use.

Comment: As I said, it is.

Comment: I‘d probably use the map_meta_cap filter instead though